# Model Training accuracy decreases and stops learning after applying Tensorflow's batch normalization

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

So I am working on making a model to classify the [German traffic signs dataset](http://benchmark.ini.rub.de/?section=gtsrb&subsection=dataset) and everything is fun and games. I build my model of 3 **convolutional** layers, 2 **fully-connected(dense)** layers, and 1 last **fully-connected(linear)** as the *logits* using **tensorflow**, I added `dropout` with keep prob. of 0.5 to the fully-connected layers and `Relu` activate for all but the the `maxpooling` and last `fully-connected(logits)` layer.

`conv Relu + maxpool > conv Relu + maxpool > conv  Relu + maxpool > dense + Relu > dense + Relu > dense(logits)`

This model with deep filters for the convolutional layers works great with validation accuracy as high as 97% and training accuracy thats close to 100%, so as a good practice I decided to add **batch normalization** for the benefits it yields; However, when I add `tf.layers.batch_normalization()` *anywhere with any order* my training accuracy dips immediately below the validation accuracy and the model seizes to learn.

[image]

Comment: How many examples in a batch are used for training? A small batch size  will reduce the effect of bn.

Comment: started with 128 then amped it up to 512